# PHP 6 Globals variables deprecated?

Tags: php, session, post, get, global

I've read stuff about global variables like `$_SESSION`, `$_GET` and `$_POST` being removed, or at least becoming deprecated in PHP 6.

Is this true? If so, what would be the alternative to retrieve data from the session or post?

Thanks!

Comment: There is this meme circulating that "globals are evil", hencewhy such ideas frequently come up. (Related) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897990/will-the-global-keyword-be-deprecated-dropped-in-future-php-versions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$_SESSION`, `$_GET`, etc. are not globals. They are actually called superglobals and will NOT be deprecated in PHP 6.

I think you heard that register globals was going to be deprecated, which means array items in variable such as `$_GET` would be converted to variables like: `$_GET['id']` to `$id`. [Read more about register globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php).

Comment: Thanks for telling me that `$_SESSION` and such are not actually globals.

Answer (score 4):

No, you've read a rumor. A wrong one.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't really that much known about PHP 6, so speculating about it doesn't make much sense.

Maybe you are referring to the removal of  `register_globals`, `session_register()` and `session_unregister()`. Which were already deprecated in PHP 5.3.

These functions are deprecated with good reason, and you really shouldn't rely on them.